# How to set development database connection and production in same project - Node JS + MongoDB + Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am building some application with NODEJS and Mongodb.
I push my commits to github (development) and to Heroku (Production).
It is frustrating to have to change every time I need to make my push the database connection:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// process.env.MONGODB_URI => for PRODUCTION HEROKU
// `mongodb://localhost/myProject` => for Local Development + GitHub Repo

mongoose.connect(**process.env.MONGODB_URI**, {family:4,useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify:false, useCreateIndex:true })
  .then(ok => {
    console.log(`Connected to Mongo! Database name: "${ok.connections[0].name}"`)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Error connecting to mongo', err)
  });
```

I would like to make some kind of function to set connections when I push commits, for each situation.

For example, this logic:

```
mongoose.connect(if process.env.MONGODB_URI works, get it. If not, get this one: `mongodb://localhost/myProject`)
```

Or even better:

```
if request is in http://localhost:3000/ => get this connection `mongodb://localhost/myProject
if not get this one => process.env.MONGODB_URI
```

I don't really want a solution, just I would like to know if that is possible, and first step to reach it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at dotenv
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Be sure to include the .env file in your .gitignore.

you should not commit the .env file. It is common for developers to list the environment variables necessary to run the program in a README or similar internal documentation.

Some developers create and maintain a .sample-env file in the source code repository. This sample file would list all the environment variables used by the app, for example:

HOST=
PORT=

A developer would then clone the repository, copy the .sample-env file into a new .env file and fill in the values.

If your app is running on a physical machine or a virtual machine (for example, Digital Ocean droplets, Amazon EC2 and Azure Virtual Machines), then you can create a .env while logged into the server and it would run just as it is done on your local machine.

Comment: actually, I am using it: process.env. I don't want to be changing for `mongodb://localhost/myProject` everytime I git push heroku master...

Comment: Okey, i have added some clarifications to my answer.

Comment: I think I didn't explain very well. I have .env working in both evironments (local and prod - heroku). But, when i push to heroku, I have to change this line mongodb://localhost/myProject to process.env.MONGODB_URI. I am wondering, if there is some trick to leave both variables, and heroku get the proper one when I push to heroku, and localhost get proper one, when I run localhost
thanks